# Text editor for translators

Tags: software-rec, text-editors, translation

I'm trying to translate a book as a hobby project and it's a bit of a pain software-wise. I don't need translation memory, just solid alignment of original and translation and highlighting of untranslated parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Linux:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/transie/index.php?title=Main_Page

"Transie is a dual-pane text editor for translators. It's made with Gambas 2.21 and runs on GNU/Linux with Qt, offering KDE integration. It's packaged for Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, OpenSUSE, Mandriva and is tested on Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat. Transie is free software, released under the GPLv3 or any later version published by the Free Software Foundation (FSF)."